# Is it possible to remove/hide response while using submit action in MS teams bot

Tags: azure-web-app-service, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, adaptive-design

I'm having MS Teams bot developed using bot framework. I have a dialog where the user choose date from date picker. For this I'm using following Adaptive card. when user select date from date picker and click ok, the message will be appeared as request sent to app. I don't want to show that message here. is there any way to remove/ hide that information  message(which is highlighted[Need to remove/hide that information message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/de5KS.png) in the image)?

[Need to remove/hide that information message (which is highlighted in yellow color)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/de5KS.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is the by default behavior of Adaptive card and we can not change it currently.